# why is the terminal or "ZSH" protesting on this command

Tags: terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

to be clear, if I run this without the alias everything is ok

but with the alias in my "zshrc" config

```
alias hh="history|awk '{print $2}'|awk 'BEGIN {FS="|"} {print $1}'|sort|uniq -c|sort -r"
```

output:

```
→ reload_zsh
/Users/redres/.zshrc:91: command not found: }{print }'|sort|uniq -c|sort -r
```

what could be the reason it is doing this

thanks R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a quoting issue . . . you've got the whole command in double-quotes, and you're also using double-quotes in the command.  A workaround for this is to escape the quotes, i.e.:

```
alias hh="history|awk '{print $2}'|awk 'BEGIN {FS=\"|\"} {print $1}'|sort|uniq -c|sort -r"
```

Here's an SO post on [escaping double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123522/set-alias-with-quotes-and-double-quotes-in-command), and here's another on [single-quotes in single-quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/bash-escaping-single-quotes-inside-of-single-quoted-strings)